# toggle menu en wordpress no me funciona

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Hola estoy diseñando mi primer theme en wordpress y me encontre una barrera cuando quiere que el sitio sea responsive. El boton en las pantallas moviles que deberia desplegar el menu no funciona. Es decir, si lo apreto no hay ningun cambio en la web.

La estructura de carpetas y archivos:

```
-Sitio web
---css
---img
---js
----main.js
---footer.php
---functions.php
---header.php
---index.php
---style.css
```

El codigo en el header es el siguiente:

```
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <title>Conejis</title>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!--Header-->
  <header class="site-header">
    <div class="header-container">
        <div class="header-logo">
            <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" class="logo">
                 <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/img/logo4.png" alt="Logo" width="160px" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <button class="toggle-menu">
            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/menu.png" alt="Menu" width="30px" />
        </button>
        <nav class="header-navigation" aria-label="Menú principal" id="header-nav">
             <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                     'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
                     'menu_id'        => 'header-menu',
                     'menu_class'     => 'header-menu',
                 ) );
             ?>
        </nav>
        <div class="header-search">
            <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
                <label>
                    <span class="screen-reader-text">Buscar en el sitio:</span>
                    <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Buscar" value="" name="s" title="Buscar en el sitio" />
                    <img class="imagen" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/buscador.png" alt="Buscar" width="30px" />
                </label>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

el codigo javascript que esta en la carpeta js/main.js es el siguiente:

```
// Selecciona el botón de menú toggle
const toggleBtn = document.querySelector('.toggle-menu');

// Selecciona la navegación del encabezado
const headerNav = document.querySelector('#header-nav');

// Agrega una verificación para asegurarte de que ambos elementos existen antes de agregar el evento de clic
if (toggleBtn && headerNav) {
  toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    headerNav.classList.toggle('active');
  });
}
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar para que el boton se abra y cierre desplegando el menu para un tamaño de pantalla menor a 500px?